# Page does not submit after clicking on lower half of button when removing validations

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jsp, struts2

I am facing an issue in my Struts2 application. Basically, on textfields, I have validations such as missing value, wrong value etc. There is then a button below these fields which submits the form when all validations are successful.

Suppose, I blur out of a textfield with a wrong value, the validation fires an error below this textfield. Now, when I supply a correct value and directly click on the upper half of the button, the validation clears and the page also submits along with it simultaneously. However, when I click on the lower half of the button, the validation just clears but the page does not submit at all. This behaviour is consistent across the application.

Now, the QA team has raised a defect for this as it could hamper user experience.

Could anyone suggest a possible fix for this other than calling the submit button click event on the mousedown event? We tried that but its causing side effects.

I cannot show the exact code as there are many collaborating CSS classes for this scenario which could cause confusion. If anyone could try to give a brief solution, it would be extremely helpful!

Comment: It's a bit difficult to see unless you have some kind of example. All I can think is that you have a html element overlaying half of the button. Or you have a wrapper element that is styled to look like the button and inside that is your actualy submit button. You are clicking the wrapper and not the button.

Comment: "I cannot show the exact code" - no need, just create a minimal reproducible example, perhaps using JS Fiddle or similar.

Comment: @Steve Tomlin: I am still working on what you said. It could be that.

Comment: @halfer: Let me check that.

Comment: Hi @Roman - oops, you corrected a British spelling of a word to the US flavour! Note that "behaviour" is fine, and a US spelling is only preferred here if that's the OP's choice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform the same function regardless of what part of the composite is invoked. If you click a submit button it should submit, if you click reset button it should reset. If you click cancel it should return to the previous page. Different functions of the same control mislead the user experience because it doesn't perform expected behavior of the button.